# What resources can I use to follow the active development of elementary OS?

Tags: development

elementary is a very large project, spanning many domains. This can make it difficult to follow on a "high" level. As a (potential) community member, what resources are available for me to follow the *active* development of elementary OS?

For example:

- Where should I look for the latest programming updates?
- Do elementary developers, designers, or supporters have blogs I can read?
- Are there social media outlets that are actively being updated?

It can sometimes be difficult to get a sense of what is happening in elementary, as is the case with many online projects and communities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Where should I look for the latest programming updates?

In general, [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/elementary) is where you can observe development happen. New code pushed to development branches, bugs being fixed, basically everything going on regarding elementary OS' codebase. You can also take a look at [which branches are most recently updated](https://code.launchpad.net/elementary/+branches?field.lifecycle=CURRENT&field.lifecycle-empty-marker=1&field.sort_by=most+recently+changed+first&field.sort_by-empty-marker=1) and [which bugs are updated most recently](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary/+bugs?orderby=-date_last_updated&start=0) via Launchpad.

If you're interested in what the latest feature / bug fix update feels like, you could set up a VM or a dedicated system (whatever you have available) running with our [daily repository](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily). This repository gets new packages every day, as it daily builds the latest development branches for elementary OS' applications and services. **You will encounter bugs and possibly untested software, so please DO NOT consider to run such an unstable system as a daily driver with important data on it**. To run the daily repository, you'll need to add `ppa:elementary-os/daily` to your repositories and fully update your system (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`).

### Do elementary developers, designers, or supporters have blogs I can read?

There are very few people around the elementary OS team which are running a blog, and those are mostly unrelated to elementary OS itself. Sam Hewitt (a designer working on elementary OS) is running [a blog](http://snwh.org/blog/), but as pointed out there is very few information about ongoing elementary OS development. I don't think there is anyone around who really blogs about recent elementary OS development.

Of course there is the [official blog](http://blog.elementary.io/). It's both posting about important events happening (big features coming, new shiny versions, etc) and answering common questions (which *are* giving insight in decisions, bug fixes worked on, etc), but it's generally aimed at the normal users, so it's not very focused on ongoing development and technical speak.

Additionally, there are a few blogs out there who either focus on elementary OS or are supporting it by occasional entries about it. **But** these blogs are mostly following development on Launchpad and more often they are simply speculating about things without asking any team members before posting about it. Therefore, sometimes they're spreading misinformation and that's the reason I would not like to link them here.

### Are there social media outlets that are actively being updated?

Beside the official blog I linked above, most information is on Google+. There is the [official Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/u/0/114635553671833442612) which posts frequent updates (although it's linking blog entries as well of course), but both [Daniel Foré](https://plus.google.com/+DanielFor%C3%A9) and [Cassidy James Blaede](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+CassidyJames) (which are basically the founding fathers of elementary) are posting about interesting stuff related to elementary OS (spiced up with personal opinion, of course). Last but not least, there is the [official G+ community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/104613975513761463450) - developers occasionally post information about new elementary OS and third-party development.

Moreover, elementary runs two Twitter Accounts, [@elementary](https://twitter.com/elementary) and [@elementaryfixes](https://twitter.com/elementaryfixes). The later one is posting whenever a bug on Launchpad is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is there any communication channel I can visit for a short dumb question on the code? (e.g. I'm trying to fix a certain bug and have a question regarding the code)

Comment: There is an IRC channel on freenode, #elementary-dev, which was set up with a bridge to elementary's internal communication channels, but afaik the bridge is currently down and the IRC channel itself is not very active. If you're trying to solve problems regarding a specific bug, I'd recommend you to post the question to the Launchpad bug report. The G+ community is most likely the best place to get in touch with developers in general, as we're very active there.